# HUAWEI E5573 stopped working (Xubuntu 16.10)

Tags: networking, usb, usb-modem, huawei, usb-modeswitch

Before that happened always when i connected modem to USB port ethernet connection was applied automatically. Now after i plug modem to USB system recognize it as a CD/DVD device, file manger opens that CD root location, and there is no available connection in the Network Manager.
And when i try :

## usb_modeswitch

it says:

```
usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 1f01 -W -J
Take all parameters from the command line
 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 2.2.5 (C) Josua Dietze 2015
 * Based on libusb1/libusbx
 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !
DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1f01
HuaweiNewMode=1
NeedResponse=0
Look for default devices ...
  found USB ID 12d1:1f01
   vendor ID matched
   product ID matched
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 04d9:a02e
  found USB ID 1d6b:0001
  found USB ID 0fce:719b
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  found USB ID 09da:c10a
  found USB ID 1d6b:0001
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 007 on bus 002
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/002/007: Permission denied
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.
Error opening the device. Abort
```

How can i fix this?
P.S. Don't know if it is related but it happened in a short time after i was doing some changes related to create .ISO image with k3b and brasero.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Huawei E1750 on Ubuntu 16.10 (worked fine on Ubuntu 16.04). I solved it by installing the latest version of [usb-modeswitch](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/usb-modeswitch/download) and [usb-modeswitch-data](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/usb-modeswitch-data/download) from Debian unstable. I also had to install the `libjim0.76` package (from the Ubuntu archive).

The issue will be fixed via [bug #1639607](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1639607).