# USB Broadband Dongle is not working

Tags: usb-modem, modem, huawei

First of all I m a newbie to ubuntu and recently installed 16.10. Then when i tried to connect to the internet my usb dongle doesn't show up.

I tried everything, googled many times. I tried adding a new connection in the regular way by going to wifi sign in top right corner and etc etc... But nothing worked.

In my dongle there is a folder named Linux and there are few files like install , 7zr , Mobile partner.dat and also a readme.txt. I ve done every step of the instructions there is in the readme.

It says login as root (sudo) and type tar (some 4 letters) Linux_install.tar.bz2.

When i execute this code terminal shows there is no files or events(something similar to that.).

Then I looked to see if my device is recognized by the OS using lsusb 
And it shows that USB Modem Huawei Technology.inc is recognized as a mass storage device.

My Dongle:
Huawei Mobile Broadband E303

---

output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 10f1:1a4f Importek 

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0930:0220 Toshiba Corp. 

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 004: ID 12d1:14fe Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem (Mass Storage Mode)

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 09da:0260 A4Tech Co., Ltd. KV-300H Isolation Keyboard

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 09da:000a A4Tech Co., Ltd. Optical Mouse Opto 510D / 
OP-620D

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: `iwconfig` command show any wireless interface?

Comment: #SuB No it said no wireless extensions.

Comment: You should install the correct driver. `tar` command extracts file inside an tarball archive. After that you should run something like `make` or `cmake` or `./configure` to compile and install the driver.

Comment: Please put the output of `lsusb`. It lets me now which chipset your dongle uses, so i can help you how to install the correct driver.

Comment: when I tried to extract using **'tar jxvf linux_install.tar.bz2'** it said

Comment: tar (child): linux: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Does [this question/answer](http://askubuntu.com/q/842837) apply to your problem?

Comment: Yes #Gunnar Hjalmarsson I m waiting for an answers. I just gave a answer to what #Sub ask me.

Comment: Please follow that link and see if the solution applies to you.

Comment: Yes i think  I m missing usb_modeswitch. But can I install debian setup on linux

Comment: Are you missing it?? `usb-modeswitch` should be installed by default, but there is a bug. And yes, in this case it works fine to download and install those packages from Debian.

Comment: okay, I m trying that; will give a reply soon

Comment: Wait a little... I'll give you an answer here which will make it much easier.

Comment: sorry for my late reply:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by a [bug in the `usb-modeswitch` package](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1639607). A fixed version of `usb-modeswitch` is currently available in my PPA.

Open a terminal window and run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gunnarhj/misc
sudo apt update
sudo apt install usb-modeswitch
```

Then reboot. Now - hopefully - all you need to do is inserting the dongle, and it should be detected automatically.

Comment: I did the above and restarted and inserted the dongle again and Now there is a msg called unable to mount the cd rom: 
In the Disks or home my dongle is not detected.